Installing Postgres : "no mapping between account names and security ids was done"
When trying to run the installer of Postgres I downloaded from the official website.
I get the error error
I have been trying to fix the issue for over two days and nothing worked.
I am doubting the reason might be that my user account has the name account name in windows
but then when I tried to modify it it was a disaster, I couldn't sign in back untill I changed it to the old name
I tried
Runing Installation as Administrator ,
Granting Permissions using the SID ,
modifying the ExtensionDebugLevel to 2 instead of 0 via regedit
...
But nothing works!!!
Please Help
